# database and table design for billions of rows of data

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.7, database-recommendation

basically i got 2 tables: `header`, `details tables`.

```
CREATE TABLE `header` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `RECORD_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `TICKER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CURR_TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `detail` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `HEADER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `BROKER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `AMOUNT` decimal(26,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

There're about 4800 ticker need to be update everyday, ticker_id (A00001, B00032...) and each ticker_id contain numbers of record everyday and i store in detail table

it works fine at the beginning, after years, header become 2.4 million row and detail table got 250 millions row, its take an hour to with simple select,

```
SELECT h.ticker_id, h.record_date , d.broker_id, d.broker_id, d.amount
FROM DETAIL 
INNER JOIN herder h 
    ON h.id = d.header_id
where h.ticker = 'A00001'
```

so i create a 'link' table to join reference them together.

```
CREATE TABLE `linkA00001` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `HEADER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DETAIL_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and the result become

```
SELECT h.ticker_id, h.record_date , d.broker_id, d.broker_id, d.amount
FROM DETAIL
INNER JOIN linkA00001 l
INNER JOIN herder h 
    ON h.id = l.header_id and d.id = l.detail_id
```

its stunning fast, from hour to few seconds, but this approach solve 1 ticker selection only, so i create 4800 link table for better performance, its do solve the selection problem, but i using java spring for my application, building over 4800 entity require 10 minutes to start the application and very hard to maintain the link table.

so my question is:

1. this approach works?
2. if not, how can i improve or just redesign this?
3. according to [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188667/best-database-and-table-design-for-billions-of-rows-of-data), its require timestamp but i never insert at detail table, is it good practices add back?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please include the full schema for the tables as well as any indexes you have defined.

Comment: the right indexes on the original tables without restructuring will improve the query time. Add a mysql tag to the question when you show the schemas (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tblname}`).

Comment: Confusion:  `TICKER_ID` is `INT`, yet your example shows a non-INT:  `A00001`.

Comment: Are you building 4800 tables with names like `linkA00001`?  I hope not.

Comment: What are you measuring that needs 26 digits?  That takes 12 bytes, making the table larger than it probably needs to be.

Comment: The title says "billions"; the data implies less than one billion.  This matters because of the size of `INT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the query:

```
SELECT h.ticker_id, h.record_date , d.broker_id, d.broker_id, d.amount
FROM DETAIL 
INNER JOIN header h 
    ON h.id = d.header_id
WHERE
    h.ticker_id = 'A00001'
```

(ignoring that `ticket_id` is an INT in the table);

The aspect of the query that will limit the results most is the value of `h.ticket_id`. To find this quickly there need to be an index on this in table `header`.

```
 CREATE INDEX ticket ON header (TICKER_ID)
```

The database then need to find the HEADER_ID quickly in the `detail` table:

```
 CREATE INDEX header ON detail (HEADER_ID)
```

What is unclear in the question here is why `detail` has an auto_increment primary key. If this isn't used in any queries, and if `HEADER_ID,BROKER_ID` is unique, then perhaps those are a better primary key for the table and as an alternate to `CREATE INDEX header` above:

```
ALTER TABLE detail
DROP ID,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (HEADER_ID, BROKER_ID);
```

This will also speed up the query as primary keys are quicker to search than secondary keys (where non-index values like `d.amount` are also needed).

Comment: thats solved my problem, thx you

Comment: Your welcome. For completeness can you show the final query time, and which change to the `detail` table did you use. `EXPLAIN {query}` will show you how the query is being executed. Also table columns shouldn't be declared `NULL` if they cannot contain null.