# Design when one column value can reference different tables

Tags: database-design

I have a table with machines data:

```
machines
----------
id
owner_id
// other data
```

We also have official machine data that comes from Germany and France.
Both have the same information:

```
# Machine data (for german and french machines)
- machine_id: to tie to machines table
- record_number: unique number for each machine, different format for each country
- machine_name: the name of the machine
- market_id: id associated with the machine market, different format for each country

# Market data (also for german and french machines)
- market_id: machine market id, different format for each country
- market_name: name of the market
- specific country information that is different for France and Germany
```

At first I though that the relational schema would be like the following:

```
machines
---------
machine_id
owner_id
// other data

machine_information
---------
machine_id
record_number
country (German or France)
machine_name
market_id

france_markets
---------
id
market_name
// France specific column data

german_markets
---------
id
market_name
// German specific column data
```

But this can make it very difficult to filter data, because when getting a machine information, we do not know which market table we have to join.

I also though about splitting the machines_information into 2, one for each country

```
machines
---------
machine_id
owner_id
// other data

france_machine_information
---------
machine_id
record_number
machine_name
market_id

german_machine_information
---------
machine_id
record_number
machine_name
market_id

france_market
----------
id
market_name
// France specific column data

german_market
----------
id
market_name
// German specific column data
```

But this also has the same problem because when getting the machine information, we do not know which machine information table we have to join.

Is there a good solution for that kind of design?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Alternatives to EAV model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261394/alternatives-to-eav-model). Also [somewhat related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227171/which-data-model-schema-to-apply-to-a-timeseries-datastore-for-data-sources-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [***polymorphic association*** or ***supertype/subtype***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113129/14868997), and is usually solved by using a base table and multiple child tables in a 1:1 relationship.

A well-known trick here is to add a `Type` column to the base table as part of the primary key, and use a computed column for `Type` in the child tables.

In your case the `Type` column is actually the country, so you could do something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE machine (
  machine_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  owner_id int ...
);

CREATE TABLE country (
  country_code char(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO country (country_code) VALUES ('FR', 'France'), ('DE', 'Germany');

CREATE TABLE machine_information (
  machine_id int REFERENCES machine (machine_id),
  --  record_number unnecessary it seems
  country_code char(2) REFERENCES country (country_code),
  machine_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  -- market_id unnecessary
  PRIMARY KEY (machine_id, country_code)
);

CREATE TABLE france_market (
  machine_id int,
  country_code AS CAST('FR' AS char(2)),
  -- France specific column data,
  PRIMARY KEY (machine_id, country_code),
  FOREIGN KEY (machine_id, country_code) REFERENCES machine_information (machine_id, country_code)
);

CREATE TABLE germany_market (
  machine_id int,
  country_code AS CAST('DE' AS char(2)),
  -- German specific column data,
  PRIMARY KEY (machine_id, country_code),
  FOREIGN KEY (machine_id, country_code) REFERENCES machine_information (machine_id, country_code)
);
```

Note the following:

- `country` does not need a surrogate key, the two letter country code is perfect as a PK.
- `machine_information` does not need a separate primary key, as its PK is made up of both the machine and country code.
- `france_market` and `germany_market` both have the same PKs, however the country code is a fixed computed column.
- They then have foreign keys back to `machine_information`.
- This means that `machine_information` contains information about which table to join, and by definition only one of either `france_market` and `germany_market` can be joined.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the full explanation! This looks good.